# Return keyword not halting execution of method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three classes (Class A, Class B and Class C). Class B holds one method (Method 1) while Class C holds one method (Method 2). The prime purpose for Class A is to do the calling for each method in their respective classes.

Class A calls method 1 inside Class B:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");// Kill Word Process
        ProcessForm processForm = new ProcessForm();
        Validation validateForm = new Validation();

        validateForm.Validate(this);//Call to method 1
        processForm.CreateDocument();//Call to method 2 still gets called after a return from this method...?                   
    }
```

which holds a condition to test if a variable is true or false and if it is true I need it to return and **NOT** return to the calling class (Class A) until the value is false:

```
//Class B
if (textIsEmpty == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in the text fields");
                return;//Shouldnt this halt execution?
            }
```

My problem is that Method 2 is still being called from Class C even with the return. I can only speculate that it has something to do with returning to a separate class.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is only mean that the return statement will only halt the execution of the method where it is being called and will not terminate the entire process

Comment: Put a break point on `return` and see what happens, does the control does there, mostly No, since ` MessageBox.Show` is a blocking call. This the `Method1` never returns and `Method2` never gets called

Comment: [Event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) FTW!

Comment: You really need to learn the basics of programming my friend, this is very simple why program doesn't halt, apply debugger and scratch the surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` ends the currently executing method ( returning the control back to the caller ). The next line within the caller is the call to another method. This is where the code is *expected* to continue.

If the next line should not be executed you should indicate by returning eg a boolean in method1 and wrapping the call to method 2 in an if statement.

---

```
//Class B
if (textIsEmpty == true) {
  MessageBox.Show("Fill in the text fields");
  return false;//Shouldnt this halt execution?
}
```

and then

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");// Kill Word Process
  ProcessForm processForm = new ProcessForm();
  Validation validateForm = new Validation();

  if (validateForm.Validate(this) ) { //Call to method 1
    processForm.CreateDocument();//Call to method 2 only if indicated by method 1      
  }             
}
```

Comment: Add code rather than providing an answer that looks like a comment

Comment: @MidTwo was in the middle of writing a sample. Often I write an answer first, then adding a sample to support my point

Answer (score 2):

**Modify Validate Method implementation on these lines**

```
public class B
{
  public bool Validate(ClassA a)
  {
    // Process ClassA / FormA object

     if (textIsEmpty == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in the text fields");
                return false;
            }
       return true;

  }
}
```

**Modify calling Validate method as follows:**

```
if(!validateForm.Validate(this))
   return;
processForm.CreateDocument();
```

This will do what you are expecting from the Program

Comment: So, that is what is expected by OP, will this not solve the issue at hand, will not call `processForm.CreateDocument()`, when not validated. What more do you expect.

Comment: @MidTwo The answers are a few minutes apart. I can believe typing up this answer and posting it while missing the notification that another answer has already been posted.

Comment: @MidTwo Ok that way I was not trying to copy the other answer, was just busy typing on Linqpad and then pasted :)

Comment: sorry I'm not being rude here :) just saying that the two answers are partly the same. I'm always being flagged by moderator on these cases. Nonetheless, i will upvote your answer so both will be fair

Comment: @MidTwo, both answers are sides of same coin, doing similar stuff.
 Though there could have been a better Answer, if OP provides more information. I agree